# Why is this not outputting anything?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why isn't this giving an output? It is meant to take a sentence as an input and then output the identification of each word.

Comment: You never call your function.

Comment: Surely it outputs a NameError and a traceback.

Comment: As @Wooble suggests, you should pay attention to your error messages from Python, and provide them with questions on here because it makes easier to see the problem

Comment: @Totem  there is no error traceback.

Comment: @user146929 It's hard to see how you avoid getting a traceback from the final `print` statement, given that there is no `parts_of_speech` name defined outside the function. Are you sure you are running the program?

Answer (score 5):

You never *call* the function. You do need to run the function to get the output:

```
print word_identify(words)
```